# Post Data from Jquery to Code behind class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Jquery registration form which takes input from the user and then stores in a local db. 
My problem is even though the jquery displays successful, the data does not get saved to the local db.
I tried adding break points to the code behind class which receives the data from the jquery but it didn't work (break), so my guess is that the jquery doesn't post the data to the code behind class.

Since this is my first time using jqueries and ajax, there might be mistakes in the code.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#register").click(function () {
    var userName=$("#userName").val();
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName=$("#lastName").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
    var country=$("#country").val();
    if (userName == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
        alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
        alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
    } else {

            $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: "SignUp.aspx/register", 
            data: {
                userID: userName, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName,
                email: email, password:password,country:country,userType:firstName},

            success: function (msg) {
                alert("successful");
            },
            error: function (err) { alert("Registration Failed, Please try again Later!") }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Here is my code behind class method:

```
    [WebMethod]

    public string register(string userID,string firstName,string lastName
        ,string email,string password,string country,string userType)
    {
        string message;
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["automobileDB"].ConnectionString;

      return  message = BusinessLogic.registerMember(userID,firstName,lastName,email,
            password,country,userType,conString);


    }
```

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the AJAX request made at all?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Add break point to success and error method and post the error.

Comment: @Yogesh there were no errors displayed

Comment: @Shehan.W  - add the following as the content type in your ajax call contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @Shehan.W - also declare your WebMethod function as a static function. See this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Comment: @Gjohn after i added that, i get the error message. Do you have a clue why the error message pops up instead of the successful?

Comment: @Shehan.W because your WebMethod needs to be static so that you can call it directly without creating an instance of the object.